# Can't export a C++ dll with visual studio

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, dll

I'm trying to create a C++ dll. I have followed the msdn tutorial but I can't compile my dll correctly.

The problem is that any function is exported. I have tested it with `dumpbin.exe` tool and `nm` tool.

In both cases, there is no detected symbols.

Here is the code of this library:

Header file:

```
#ifndef NLIB_H
#define NLIB_H

#ifdef _WINDLL
#define NLIB_EXPORTS __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define NLIB_EXPORTS __declspec( dllimport )
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"{
#endif

    NLIB_EXPORTS int fun1(int n);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif
```

Source code file:

```
#include "nlib.h"

int fun1(int n) {
    return 100;
}
```

Comment: do you define `_WINDLL` when you build the dll?

Comment: Yes, is defined by Visual Studio if you select Dynamic library as project type. Also, VS 2013 indicates which macros are defined, son I'm sure that `_WINDLL` is working.

Comment: Where is `_WINDLL` defined - in a header file somewhere, or in the project settings?

Comment: In the project settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the error. It's necessary to add `NLIB_EXPORTS` to the `*.c` file also, like this:

```
#include "nlib.h"

NLIB_EXPORTS int fun1(int n) {
    return 100;
}
```